# PHP throwing "undefined variable" notices

Tags: php, error-reporting

I want to log all errors except for undefined variable entries... shouldn't this do it?

```
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

Comment: Who cares? Fix the problems.

Comment: Those notices aren't to be taken lightly...

Comment: Why would I care about those notices?  Honestly, they don't matter and you can turn them off.

Comment: Thanks to the wonders of the Internet, you don't have to suffer all the people pointing and laughing.

Comment: All these people pointing and laughing aren't getting any reputation for answering the question

Comment: @Webnet: You should care about notices because they are errors.  If you want to ignore them, that's fine...  But that's your choice to ignore the error...  But you can't say they *don't matter*, because they most definitely do.  Most of us like having **correct** code that does not raise errors of any kind (hence why the commenting above)...

Comment: @Webnet: Our professional reputation would suffer if we didn't point and laugh at someone supporting unacceptable practices in our industry. That's more important than our Stack Overflow reputation.

Comment: @DanGrossman: I'd proclaim the reputation here suffers due to the display of cargo cult programming advise (oh noes, all notices are always errors, use moar isset, fix ur dirty problems). @downvoters: That's for unclear and useless questions, not disagreement.

Comment: How do you define/declare variables in PHP to avoid the error? It says nothing in here about that for instance: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: This will declare it: `var $var;` though I think it would be better to just to `$var = null;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These notices are getting logged through your custom error handler. This is the thing you have to adapt. Look for `set_error_handler()` and the function it defines. It has a declaration like:

```
function user_err_log ($errno, $errstr, $file, $line, $context) {
```

And you want to check `$errno` to separate notices from errors:

```
    if ($errno == E_NOTICE or $errno == E_USER_NOTICE) {
         // log to a debug file instead
         return;
    }
```

The advantage of `error_reporting(0x0000)` and the error suppression operator `@` over syntactic supression with `isset` is that vital notices still reach your custom error handler. But you have to manually sort them out, if you don't care about them. Which for **logging *errors***, you rightly shouldn't. (I would personally devise a method to spool notices elsewhere, just in case.)

Answer (score 9):

It will hide all notices, but this should do it:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

You should fix the problems instead though.

Comment: Downvoted why?  I gave the answer and provided the "better" solution.

Comment: You said nothing about logs.  The error_reporting argument I provided **is the correct solution**. (See for yourself in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).  Are you using a custom error handler or calling error_log() anywhere?

Comment: Error logging is not the same as error reporting so it shouldn't be surprising to you that you still get errors in the logs even though you've turned reporting off. If you don't want errors in your logs, turn the logging off and you can be blissfully unaware of the underlying problems in our application.

Comment: I understand that, but you said they are still showing up in your logs, so you already are logging errors at somepoint. I'm asking how you are currently logging them (custom error handler or error_log()?).

Comment: I want to log all errors except for undefined variable entries

Comment: @Webnet: then you should rephrase your question.